# How to apply dilation on particular region of the image?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have applied dilation on the whole image (img) but bold text/logo on the upper left corner is still untouched. It happens every time when there is logo or some bold text in the input image

```
dilated_img = cv2.dilate(img, np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8))
```

Now I want to re-apply dilation with higher value (`> 7`) but only on that region. I can't apply dilation with higher value on the whole image because then it gives me poor results. I want to apply low-valued dilation on the whole image and then re-apply high-valued dilation on the regions that haven't got dilated

(This should be generalized on every image and not only this one)

How can I achieve that?

[image: input image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply an operation to a rectangular box you can pass in the region by index.

So first dilate the whole image:

```
dilated_img = cv2.dilate(img, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8))
```

Then overwrite the region requiring higher dilation:

```
dilated_img[10:50, 30:40] = cv2.dilate(img[10:50, 30:40], np.ones((20, 20), np.uint8))
```

Comment: Yes,, that will work on this particular image. But how can I find the region to apply the second dilation?

Comment: Detecting areas with bold text is a more complicated problem. Maybe try thresholding, dilating until non-bold are removed. This will remove skinny characters, leaving only bold. Follow by a large smoothing filter to give a smooth positive response where there bold characters. Any region with a value over a threshold will probably have bold text.